# Can I put checkbox and hidden input inside a label?

Tags: html, accessibility

I have a list of possible products a user can buy. For doing it, I use ul tag combined with li.
Every element has a checkbox that allows the user to choose if select the product or not.

Some products have related information. In order to describe this, I would like to store the data inside an hidden input. But because the selection and the information are related to a product I thought to use a label that contains the checkbox and the hidden input.

Something like

```html
<label class="product">
  <input class="product-checkbox" name="product1" type="checkbox">
  <input type="hidden" name="product1-information" value="{...}" />
  <span class="product-name">Product1</span>
</label>
```

If I understood correctly, a label cannot refer to an hidden input but in the above example, accordingly to the w3c, the labeled control is the checkbox.

Anyway I'm wandering if a label can contains checkbox **and** an hidden input.

So, is the above snipper correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on both counts. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

> The form control that a label is labeling is called the *labeled control* of the label element. Multiple labels can be associated with the same form control:
>
> ```
> <label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
> <input id="username">
> <label for="username">Forgot your username?</label>
> ```
>
> Elements that can be associated with a `<label>` element include `<button>`, `<input>` **(except for `type="hidden"`)**, `<meter>`, `<output>`, `<progress>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`.

(emphasis mine)

That makes it pretty clear to me that (a) multiple things inside a `<label>` block is entirely acceptable, and (b) `hidden` inputs will not be considered targets of the label.